# Extracting 7z file using 7-zip-jbinding and preserving unix file mode

Tags: java, 7zip

How to extract a 7z file using 7-zip-jbinding (http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/) while preserving the Unix file mode (rwx)? I use Oracle Java 7. After extracting 7z file using 7-zip-jbinding, my files are no longer executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of 7z.

From *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z#Limitations)*:

> The 7z format does not store filesystem permissions (such as UNIX owner/group permissions or NTFS ACLs), and hence can be inappropriate for backup/archival purposes.

If you control the archive creation, you can build a tarball before compressing it with 7z. However you need the extra mechanism to extract the tar. All workarounds will involve something of the sort.